# SQLEXEC statement fails

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, visual-foxpro

What is wrong with this statement:

```
lnResult = SQLEXEC(oGv.pnConnhandle, 'EXEC ClientSecurity.UsersCloneSP','userz')
```

The stored procedure is qualified by a database schema name. Do I have to further qualify the stored procedure?

`EXEC ClientSecurity.UsersCloneSP` executes successfully in management studio query window.

Comment: Try adding the database name as well.

Comment: I added the database name and it worked ok. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It would have worked, if you had the database name in the connection string. You could also see why it failed if you checked that with aerror().